# Canvas drawImage function insert img after canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

```
 var canvas = document.getElementById("canvaspreview");
       canvas.width=w;canvas.height=h;
       var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");    
      var img=new Image();


      img.src=url;img.width=w;img.height=h;
      ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,w,h);
```

We expect from this code to draw the image by its Url in Canvas DOMElement ,However, when i inspect the DOM, i note that a new DOMELement IMG has been inserted after canvas .

Is there another syntax recommended , Known that the DOM seems to be like this:

```
<div id="bigpreview" style="display:block;">
  <canvas id="canvaspreview" width="800" height="520">Canvas not supported </canvas> 
</div>
```

And the result that i get :

```
<div id="bigpreview" style="display:block;">
  <canvas id="canvaspreview" width="800" height="520">Canvas not supported </canvas> 
  <img src="" width="" height=""/>
</div>
```

Comment: that's, umm, weird.  The `img` object shouldn't appear in the DOM unless you explicitly put it there.

Answer (score 0):

FOUND!

Drawing image should be done **after** image loading ,

```
img.onload=function(e){
 ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,w,h); 
  // بقية الكود هنا

}
```

See this [example](http://corehtml5canvas.com/code-live/ch04/example-4.1/example.js) :

Comment: well, yes, that's obvious, but it doesn't explain why the img tag apparently ended up in your DOM.